# SharePoint 2013 People Search Configuration

Tags: user-profile-service

Having trouble getting search results for People in SharePoint search.

Active Directory user profiles are imported to site. Followed set up directions found here: http://www.sharepointconfig.com/2013/05/how-to-create-a-simple-sharepoint-2013-people-directory/

Having trouble with the `contentclass = spspeople`, it is returning 0 relevant results.

Has anyone had any experience setting this up and ran into this issue?

Comment: Is the search crawling your mysite host? With `sps3://` protocol?

Comment: Crawl is set up and everything should be getting indexed, which is where I'm confused. I have a crawl set up for everything on the site. For example http:// _domainname_ / and sps3:// _domainname_ . Should I run two separate crawls? One for  _domainname_ /intranet and one for _domainname_ /my ? _/my_ is the mysite host. Searching for content works fine on the site.

Comment: If you have the crawl set up on sps3://<Your SharePoint site or my site host>, are you getting any crawl errors? Have you granted the Crawl account access to the User Profile Service?

Comment: You might be on to something. "Error in the Microsoft SharePoint Server People Protocol Handler" is an error from the crawl, didn't see it before. Checking on the crawl account access.

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott access is set up as it should be for the User Profile Service. Still getting the crawl error.

Comment: What is the crawl error?

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott The error message I get is: "Error in the Microsoft SharePoint Server People Protocol Handler. ( Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Comment: Do yo have a working User Profile Service? Are you using SSL for your mysites?

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott User Profile Service is working, and wasn't sure about SSL, so to be sure I included sps3s://domain/ in the crawl, no change

Comment: Do you access he my site host with HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott HTTP

Comment: OK, then you are not using SSL and don't need sps3s:// just sps3://<MySIte Host URL>. What permission does the crawl account have on the User Profile Service?

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott Yeah, I tried the crawl with the sp3s:// and without and nothing changed so I removed it. The crawl account has full control, including "Retrieve People Data for Search Crawlers".

Comment: You shouldn't have Full Control, just Retrieve People Data.

Comment: @MatthewMcDermott I changed the permission and didn't have any luck with that either

Comment: I didn't expect that to fix it, just letting you know the right way. Something is messed up in your configuration. I would go back the beginning and  review the configuration step by step. The cawl log should be your guide.

Comment: I just Binged around and am wondering if the web app you are using for the sts3:// crawl has a top level site collection AND does that web app have a service app connection to the UPSA?

Answer (score 1):

Do you find you imported users from AD in User Profile Service Application under Manage User Profiles?

If not, check under Search Service Application: Manage Content Sources -> Edit Content Source if sps3 is included.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh582311.aspx

The sps3 portion should look like in the above MS acticle described:

> sps3://My_Site_host_URL or sps3s://My_Site_host_URL, where
>   My_Site_host_URL is the URL for the web application where you deployed
>   the My Sites site collection

Comment: AD users are available under Manage User Profiles.

Comment: updated my answer, maybe your My Site site collection URL is wrong

Comment: I'll take another look at the site collection URL and the Crawl

Comment: Still no avail. I'm stumped